# Minimal working example for ppchtex

Tags: context

I want to use ppchtex in Latex.
In the file https://tug.org/pracjourn/2010-1/braslau/braslau.pdf
there is the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{m-ch-en}
\begin{document}
\startchemical
\chemical [ONE,Z0357,SB1357,MOV1,Z037,SB137,MOV1,Z01,SB1]
[C,H,H,H,C,H,H,O,H]
\stopchemical
\end{document}
```

If I run it with pdflatex, I got :

```
    ! LaTeX Error: File `m-ch-en.sty' not found.
    Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
    or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
```

If I type `m-ch-en.tex`

I got a new error message :

```
! I can't find file `syst-gen.mkii'.
l.34 \input syst-gen.mkii
```

syst-gen.mkii is not present on my system (Debian sid with texlive-full installed).

Ppchtex has some features I really need. Could someone give me a working minimal example of its use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The file is using a latex wrapper around a Context Mkii module, but Context Mkii is no longer distributed.

Your example loads, but gives errors, in texlive 2020,2021,2022.

You can avoid the error by forcing the expl3 backend to load earlier, the above image was made using texlive 2022 and

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=pdftex]{expl3}
\usepackage{m-ch-en}
\begin{document}
\startchemical
\chemical [ONE,Z0357,SB1357,MOV1,Z037,SB137,MOV1,Z01,SB1]
[C,H,H,H,C,H,H,O,H]
\stopchemical
\end{document}
```

Your original example does work unchanged in texlive 2019, which is available for example at Overleaf, see

https://overleaf.com/read/jwyshqktjjst#c35a48

To get this to work in texlive 2023 or later you would need to copy the context mkii files locally. Looking at the log, you would need copies of these four files, only the first of which is still provided by default).

```
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-mis.mkii
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/syst-gen.mkii
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/syst-fnt.mkii
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/context/modules/mkii/ppchtex.mkii
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation.  In short, ppchtex seems to be deprecated. I don't think it is worth investing time in it, or is  it?

Comment: @AlainBertrand it looks like deprecated is putting it politely. It's based on context mk 2 which the context team asked to be removed from texlive, that said texlive ought to "rescue" the other three mkii modules (as they did for the first as it is used somewhere) or remove the latex wrapper which is competely non-functional as currently distributed. You could report it to the texlive list (or I could)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you seem to be very very knowledgeable in these subjects, I think that a report from you to  texlive list would be  better done and would have more weight.